# Programmatically add label to Message App in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, message, swift3, ios10

I know this is new with iOS10 and all, but Im trying to build a simple ms messageappextension app, and all the tutorials Ive found add their labels, buttons, etc via storyboard.

I hate autlayout and don't use storyboard, so I need to find how to add elements programmatically. This is what Ive tried:

```
//main label
        pointsLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width * 0.5, height: view.bounds.height * 0.1)
        pointsLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width * 0.5, y: view.bounds.width * 0.7)
        pointsLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
        pointsLabel.textAlignment = .center
        pointsLabel.text = "Testing 123"
        pointsLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: screenSize.height * (30/screenSize.height))

        view.addSubview(pointsLabel)
```

This is how Id normally make a label, and this works when the MSMessagesAppViewController is in full view like this:

[image]

However when its like this even though the positioning of the center is based on view.bounds, when the view shrinks here, the label is still displayed out of view:

[image]

Ive found that this is called when the size changes, however even resetting the center here does nothing:

```
override func willTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
        // Called before the extension transitions to a new presentation style.

        // Use this method to prepare for the change in presentation style.

        print(view.bounds.height)
        pointsLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width * 0.5, y: view.bounds.width * 0.7)
    }
```

Other than just switching back in forth between different heights, what is the correct way to add a label programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Change your center calculation to use the height of the superview for `y`, rather than a portion of the width:

```
pointsLabel.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width * 0.5, y: view.bounds.height * 0.5)
```

While compact, the width is actually greater than the height, so `view.bounds.width * 0.7` was pushing your label off the screen.